# Update multiple tables using a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want use a stored procedure to update multiple tables in a db.  Each table has a GUID as the PK and there are FK's between the tables.

For example, one table is "Tool" with a column ID (the guid) and another table is "Type" with ID as guid again.  There is a column in Tool called "TYPE_ID" that is a FK to the table Type with Type's Guid stored in it. I want to first update the Tool table and then after, update the Type table based on that FK.

```
UPDATE Tool
    SET Name=@Name, [Enabled]=@Enabled, TestMode=@TestMode, SerialNumber=@SerialNumber, 
        Andon=@Andon, ChimeZone=@ChimeZone, Number=@ToolNumber
    WHERE ID=@ID

Update Type
    SET Type=@Type
    WHERE Tool.ID=@ID AND
        Tool.TYPE_ID=Type.ID
```

I know that this code is incorrect for the second update, but this is the gist of how I would like to be able to do it.  Is there a way to not have to SELECT the FK Guid, store it, and use it the next update?  If that is the only way, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your second update like this, joining the `Tool` table to the `Type` table:

```
UPDATE ty
    SET Type = @Type
    FROM Tool to
        INNER JOIN Type ty
            ON to.TYPE_ID = ty.ID
    WHERE to.ID = @ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can UPDATE FROM clause:

```
UPDATE Type
SET Type=@Type
FROM Tool INNER JOIN TYPE 
    ON Tool.TYPE_ID=Type.ID
    WHERE Tool.ID=@ID;
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx for full UPDATE syntax.